# Why doesn't Chrome or Firefox add Doctype to txt file when being opened

Tags: google-chrome, doctype

If you save a txt file and open it w/ chrome or firefox, I noticed that the the doctype declaration isn't added when I inspect the element in question. Instead it's just 'html.'

Is there any reason for this? Because it does make a difference to the 'pre' format's style and layout when you do add doctype html.

Edit: OK, when a browser opens up a txt (whether locally or thorugh HTTP) it does not open a txt file, but converts it to raw html. And Matt Ball is wrong - because the browser is not opening a txt file - it's converting a txt file to html. Example: gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4300/pg4300.txt Now inspect it's element - you'll notice it's not display the actual txt file but an html document

Comment: Why would a plain text file have an HTML doctype? And why would a browser add one to a file you created?

Comment: @user2246674 it seems pretty obvious that the OP is talking about opening a `.txt` file locally, not over HTTP.

Comment: *Chrome does not add a DOCTYPE* - even when a resource is opened as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The doctype is a signal from the programmer to the browser, originally intended as a [shibboleth](http://xkcd.com/806/) to indicate that [the programmer knows what they're doing.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)

The browser already knows what it's doing when it's opening a text file: *not* opening an HTML file.

Comment: In real HTML, sure, a doctype makes a difference. But a text file isn't HTML, and the browser doesn't need to (by way of a doctype) tell itself that it knows what it's doing.